# Meta Description no se muestra correctamente

Tags: html5, google-chrome

Cuando realizo la búsqueda de mi sitio en Google, la descripción no figura correctamente.

Mi descripción es esta:

```html
<meta name="description" content="Somos una agencia estratégica mobile. Creamos momentos memorables para las marcas en todo el mundo. Cada segundo cuenta y somos apasionados en lo que hacemos.">
```

En vez de figurar lo que escribí en el `meta description`, figura lo siguiente:

**logo. Home; Propuesta; Experiencias; Trabajos; Reality.Up; Contacto. logo. Somos una agencia...**

Cómo puedo hacer para arreglarlo? Parece como si estuviera mostrando lo que hay dentro del `navbar`como descripción.

Comment: esto es porque tu sitio no es tan relevante como para mandar los spy cada 5 minutos en busca de cambios debes esperar aproximandamente 48 horas mas o menos para que se vuelva a evaluar tu sitio o usar la herramienta de [webmaster tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812) tampoco es del todo instantanea pero es alguito mas rapido que esperar

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar ahora con la herramienta que me sugeriste. Saludos!